# Display a editable spreadsheet on a php page

Tags: php, mysql, spreadsheet

I'm new to PHP programming language.

Currently, i want to develop a page that displays something like an excel spreadsheet (with self-defined column headers).
It allows users to key in data onto the 'spreadsheet' and when they submit it (maybe a submit button at the bottom), the data will be saved into mySQL database.

May i know if this can be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use google spreadsheet API:

The Google Spreadsheets Data API allows client applications to view and update Spreadsheets content in the form of Google Data API feeds. Your client application can request a list of a user's spreadsheets, edit or delete content in an existing Spreadsheets worksheet, and query the content in an existing Spreadsheets worksheet.

http://code.google.com/apis/spreadsheets/data/1.0/developers_guide_php.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. e.g: google docs and some other online editing/office applications. But you may need to know more than php.

Answer (score 0):

try something like zoho sheet, getting data into your database will have to use something else though
https://sheet.zoho.com/